# What is the term use for these motorbikes?

Tags: motorcycle, custom, classic

I am looking at bikes like this:

https://www.pinterest.pt/pin/256071928792526793/

http://www.wrenchmonkees.com/bikes

What terms are used to categorize those? I have not been able to find any websites that have actual models for sale including prices. Eventually you need to go visit a physical store, but it could be interesting to get a feel of the different bikes and the corresponding price range.

Comment: @SolarMike - You really didn't read the question, eh? He's asking what is the style of bike, not where to buy one at.

Answer (score 4):

They are typically called a [***Cafe Racer***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caf%C3%A9_racer). You don't usually buy these. You *make them*. I mean, I'm sure you can find indie shops which will make you one, but they are usually a modified version of regular street bikes. I'm sure you can also find ones which can be bought from individuals who've made them. You aren't going to go down to your Yamaha dealer or Powersports shop and buy one new, though.

Comment: Both ducati and triumph now make pretty much these off the shelf. I think harley may now too. Check out the ducati scrambler in its many guises, and the triumph street cup

Comment: @Mauro - It doesn't surprise me. If there's money to be made ...

Comment: Triumph Thruxton is a classic example of a Cafe Racer.